# Oracle query not working properly in SSIS

Tags: oracle, ssis

I am facing a strange problem , when I connecting Oracle from SSIS and running below query it is not applying filter criteria

```
SELECT * FROM Table_Schema.Table_Name where trunc(Date_Column) >='01-APR-14'
```

but this is giving me data older than 01 April also. But when I am running same query in Oracle it is working absolutely fine.
What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried applying a format mask to the date you are passing in - you should always do this by default. You could substitute your date for sysdate (or getdate() in sqlserver) and see if it performs correctly. Also try removing the trunc.